# Is "numerate" a verb or only an adjective?

Tags: etymology, verbs, translation, numbers, mathematics

I am at the moment looking into technical English terms used in mathematics.

The terminology in fractions (such as 1/8, 2/8 etc.) is that the bottom is called the *denominator* and the top the *numerator*.

- The bottom makes sense as it *denominates* the fraction - it gives it it's name (one **eight**h, two **eight**hs etc.).
- The top is a bit tricky for me. It *counts* the number of bits we have (**one** eighth, **two** eighths etc.) but can I say that it *numerates* the bits?

Does *numerate* mean *count*? Does the verb *to numerate* even exist? I am able to find many uses of it as a verb when searching (and Google Translate [translates it](https://translate.google.com/#en/da/to%20numerate) to *to give numbers* or *to number*) but I am sitting with an official dictionary from my native language, and "to numerate" is not there.

Here is a screenshot of the online dictionary [Ordbogen.com](http://www.ordbogen.com/opslag.php?word=numerate&dict=a000) (in Danish):

[image]

It displays *numerate* as an adjective only, and *to **be** numerate* would be fine. This means *a person who is good with numbers* (in Danish: *talkyndig*) and is not really getting me closer to "counting" the bits in the fraction.

Maybe it is just a name invented for fractions with no other meaning to it than having something to do with numbers? An adjective over time turned into a noun? Or is my dictionary incomplete?

For reference (and this is the reason I am looking this up in detail in English) I can tell that the Danish equivalents are very, very logical and I was hoping the English versions were as well:

- The *denominator* is in Danish called *nævneren*, literally meaning *the namer*, and
- the *numerator* is in Danish called *tælleren*, literally meaning *the counter*.

Comment: I think the "numerate" word you're looking for is *enumerate* (common in English), and the equivalent of your Danish *tælleren* is English *tally*. And thank you for posting a well-researched, well-presented question. +1.

Comment: Hello, Steeven. ELU is aimed at linguists, and a reasonable amount of sensible research is expected to be carried out, and the results shown. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numerate), for instance defines the verb _numerate_ as an alternative to _enumerate_. [Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/) is a good place to start to look for etymologies (and actually covers the Latin origins of _numerator_).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is the question off-topic on this site?

Comment: @Steeven - no it is not off-topic, you have presented your research and you are asking for help. Etymology can help in this case but you are not supposed to be familiar with it as a new user. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=numerator&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: Yes; as it stands, it lacks _reasonable_ research. Josh is wilfully misinterpreting site rules. If you look at the Help Center, you will find what the actual site regulations are. You can also check on resources considered general reference. The Online Etymological Dictionary is one; **English** dictionaries (AHD; Collins; M-W; ODO; CED etc) are a given.  / Adding the relevant references to your question would remove the 'lack of reasonable research' problem – but would seem to provide your answers.

Comment: @Steeven - the research you present is reasonable and shows effort. It will take time, as senior users know well, to familiarize with the huge amount of reference available online, but you are going in the right direction.

Comment: @Josh Now that I've provided the links, it shouldn't take that much time in this case.

Comment: IMHO, a non-native speaker could consult a bunch of English language references and still be confused by the difference between "numerate" and "enumerate." (I have these problems in Danish.) This is a "grammar" (verb form) question as much as it is a "dictionary" question. I would have put this question on English Language Learners, but consider it on-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

"Numerate" is an adjective that refers to a person being capable in "numeracy."

The verb form is ["enumerate."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerate) That is to "ascertain the number of."

Answer (score 1):

The English word “numerator” actually seems to be taken from French *numerateur*/Latin *numerator,* where it was already established as a word. Since the word was not derived in English, the existence of "numerator" doesn’t definitely mean a verb “to numerate” exists or ever existed in English (compare *doctor* and *emperor*).

However, in this particular case, a corresponding verb turns out to exist. The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) says

> numerate, *v.*
>
> *trans.* To number, compute, or calculate; to enumerate (things, etc.). Also *intr.*

The three most recent OED examples of its use are as follows:

> - 1900   *Pall Mall Mag.* Sept.–Dec. 216   I have not numerated Noël's birthday presents, because I wish to leave something to the imagination of my young readers.
> - 1938   *Science* 3 June 396   We numerate the irreducible clusters in any order from 1 to *m,* where *m* is the total number of irreducible clusters.
> - 1979   *Business Week* (Nexis) 26 Feb. 65   More than 90% of Japanese raw materials and other imports are numerated and funded in dollars.

It is not a common word. I don't think I've ever used it or heard it used. The OED gives its frequency as three dots out of eight, compared to five dots out of eight for enumerate (v.) and number (v.). According to the “[Key to frequency](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/)”,

> Band 3 contains words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These words are not commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but at the same time they are not overly opaque or obscure. Nouns include *ebullition* and *merengue,* and examples of adjectives are *amortizable, prelapsarian, contumacious, agglutinative, quantized, argentiferous.* In addition, adjectives include a marked number of very colloquial words, e.g. *cutesy, dirt-cheap, teensy, badass, crackers.* Verbs and adverbs diverge to opposite ends of the spectrum of use encompassed by this band. Verbs tend to be either colloquial or technical, e.g. *emote, mosey, josh, recapitalize.*
>   About 20% of all non-obsolete OED entries are in Band 3.